# Implementing an inner product using pyspark

Tags: python, functional-programming, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement a dot product using pyspark in order to learn pyspark's syntax.

I've currently implemented the dot product like so:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def inner(rdd, rdd2):
    return (rdd.zip(rdd2)
        .map(lambda x: reduce(op.mul, x))
        .reduce(lambda x,y: x + y)
    )
```

My solution feels inelegant (particularly my lambda function). I'd like to know if there would be a more 'pysparkian' way of writing this.

Furthermore, are there performance considerations that I should be thinking about with regards to this problem (i.e. does my dot product solution not scale well)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since zipped RDD contains only two-element tuples using using `reduce` doesn't makes sense. You can safely replace

```
lambda x: reduce(op.mul, x)
```

with

```
lambda x: x[0] * x[1]
```

or standalone function:

```
def mul(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return x * y
```

Final `reduce` can be replaced with a simple `sum`. Putting these two pieces together:

```
def inner(xs, ys):
    return xs.zip(ys).map(lambda xy: xy[0] * xy[1]).sum()
```

The only part that remains is `zip` function. It requires both that both RDDs have the same number of partitions and elements per partition. While the first part is pretty easy to achieve keeping a correct order and balancing number of elements can be tricky. You can try to generalize your function using `joins`:

```
def inner(xs, ys):
    def swap(xi):
        x, i = xi
        return i, x

    # We use sortBy key to avoid shuffling during join
    xs_i = xs.zipWithIndex().map(swap).sortByKey()
    ys_i = ys.zipWithIndex().map(swap).sortByKey()

    return xs_i.join(ys_i, ).values().map(lambda xy: xy[0] * xy[1]).sum()
```

It will be less efficient than your current solution but more robust.